# How to SELECT from an INNER JOIN table with multiple constraints?

Tags: mysql, sql

Find the names of lecturers who teach at both undergraduate and postgraduate level.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname)) as Lecturer_Name  
FROM Lecturer INNER JOIN Subject on Lecturer.id = Subject.lecturer  
WHERE yearlevel IN(1, 2, 3) and WHERE yearlevel = 9  
GROUP BY Lecturer.id
```

This returns nothing from the 2 tables *Lecturer* and *Subject*, where yearlevel = (1,2,3) in undergrad and yearlevel = 9 is postgrad.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is **not** a function, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and is applied on the whole selected rows. To make things clearer, remove those redundant parentheses, i.e. `SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple `WHERE` statements in an SQL query. You need to remove the second one. And `DISTINCT` is not a function; you need a space instead of brackets to make use of it.

Also, note that `9` is not in `1, 2, 3`, so having `WHERE yearlevel IN(1, 2, 3) AND yearlevel = 9` will not yield any results. You additionally want to make use of an **`OR`** statement instead. Or better yet, simply include it in your `IN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as Lecturer_Name  
FROM Lecturer INNER JOIN Subject on Lecturer.id = Subject.lecturer  
WHERE yearlevel IN(1, 2, 3, 9)  
GROUP BY Lecturer.id
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing to notice is that you do not need that WHERE after the AND.
Other than that, your condition does not seem to be correct:

```
yearlevel IN (1, 2, 3) AND yearlevel = 9
```

if yearlevel must be either 1, 2, or 3 (as per the first condition), it will not be 9. And if the yearlevel must be 9 (as per the second condition), it will not be 1, 2, or 3. So you will never be able to satisfy both conditions at the same time, therefore never. One way to solve this is to include all in the first condition and remove the second:

```
yearlevel IN (1, 2, 3, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` is not a function.  Also, you almost never need `SELECT DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY`.

I would suggestion:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(' ', l.firstname, l.lastname) as Lecturer_Name  
FROM Lecturer l INNER JOIN
     Subject s
     ON l.id = s.lecturer  
WHERE yearlevel IN (1, 2, 3) AND yearlevel = 9  ;
```

Note that I also added table aliases.

EDIT:

Actually, as I read the query, I think you intend:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(' ', l.firstname, l.lastname) as Lecturer_Name  
FROM Lecturer l INNER JOIN
     Subject s
     ON l.id = s.lecturer  
GROUP BY CONCAT_WS(' ', l.firstname, l.lastname)
HAVING SUM(yearlevel IN (1, 2, 3)) > 0 AND
       SUM(yearlevel = 9) > 0  ;
```